# Delete/Add Row based upon Lookup Value From other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, append, delete-row

I have two sheets in the same workbook. Sheet 2 is "DCT Accounts". Sheet 1 is "DCT".

If Column J in "DCT Accounts" says "Add Account", I want to append columns A, B, and C from "DCT Accounts" to the bottom of "DCT".

If Column K in "DCT Accounts" says "Close Account", I want to delete the entire row from "DCT".

I created the following lookup from "DCT Accounts" to "DCT". How do I append or delete rows based upon columns J & K?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('DCT Accounts'!A4,DCT!B:B,1,0),VLOOKUP('DCT Accounts'!B4,DCT!B:B,1,0))
```

Data in both sheets starts with row 4.

DCT
[image: DCT Worksheet Template with Existing Data]

DCT Accounts
[image: DCT Accounts Template]

"DCT Accounts" is the same story, 700+ rows, but we're using column D as the lookup (which is a formula), but gives us the lookup we want.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, at least for me... If in J:J of "DCT Accounts" is "Add Account" the range A:C of the respective row is copied at the end of "DCT" sheet, but If column K 'says' "Close Account", what row from "DCT" to be deleted? The same row number with the one in "DCT Accounts"? I have some doubts... If not, what unique key to be used to identify the appropriate row to be deleted? In which column such a key should be found? In A:A for both worksheets? Since columns A, B and C ar copied in the other worksheet, theoretically the key should be in the same column...

Comment: Hi there thanks for the note. I should have clarified better.  Column D in the Sheet "DCT Accounts"  can be used as a lookup to column B in "DCT" .  So in other words, for deleting the row, if Column K of "DCT Accounts" has Close Account, then we can use column D in "DCT Accounts" as a lookup to delete the row in "DCT" sheet that has a matching lookup.

Comment: It looks that it is something strange/ilogic in the way you define the unique code/lookup. Since you copy **only** columns A, B, C from "DCT Accounts", I logically suppose that this lookup should be, in the sheet where they are copied from, **in the same A:C range**. Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: Your way of explaining should work only if values in B:B are the same with the ones in D:D, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification question...

So, please test the next code, designed exactly how you suggested. It should be very fast, using arrays and due to that, working in memory and deleting the rows at once:

```
Sub DeleteAddRow()
 Dim wsDA As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, lastRDA As Long, lastRD As Long
 Dim arrDA As Variant, rngDel As Range, arrD As Variant, arrCopy As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 
 Set wsDA = Worksheets("DCT Accounts")
 Set wsD = Worksheets("DCT")
 lastRDA = wsDA.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRD = wsD.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arrDA = wsDA.Range("A4:K" & lastRDA).Value 'place the range in an array
 arrD = wsD.Range("A4:K" & lastRDA).Value   'place the range in an array
 
 ReDim arrCopy(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(arrDA))  'initially redim the array but transposed
                                            'transposed to allow redim preserve to
                                            'the last dimension
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrDA)
    If arrDA(i, 10) = "Add Account" Then
        k = k + 1: arrCopy(1, k) = arrDA(i, 1): arrCopy(2, k) = arrDA(i, 2)
        arrCopy(3, k) = arrDA(i, 3)        'fill the array with the data to be copied
    End If
    If arrDA(i, 11) = "Close Account" Then
        For j = 1 To lastRD
            If arrDA(i, 4) = arrD(j, 2) Then 'create the range to be deleted at once
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = wsD.Range("A" & j + 3)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, wsD.Range("A" & j + 3))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
 Next i
 if k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrCopy(1 To 3, 1 To k)   'keep in the array only non empty elements
 If Not rngDel is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp             'delete the range at once (very fast)
 lastRD = wsD.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'determine the last row after deletion
 'drop the array values to the last empty row:
 If k > 0 Then
      wsD.Range("A" & lastRD + 1).Resize(k, 3).Value = _
              WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrCopy)
 End If
End Sub
```

From procedural point of view, I think it would be good to clear "Add Account" from the sheet, after inputting the range in the array, or replacing it with something like "Account added". To do this, in order to avoid running the code twice for the same data and double the same account in "DCT".

But, firstly it would be good that you check the logic of determining the range to be copied (from D, or from B column...).

Comment: Thank you for the response here!  So upon executing the macro I get the following error on this line:  If arrDA(i, 4) = arrD(j, 2) Then 'create the range to be deleted at once .   It says "Run time error 13 Type Mismatch.  From the range question, I hopefully will make this a bit easier on you.  I created 3 additional columns in the "DCT Accounts" sheet, columns L:N are the ones that need to be added DCT sheet.  Column M contains the lookup value that will correspond with column B in the DCT Sheet for both the adding/deleting scenario.

Comment: If Column J in 'DCT Accounts' Sheet says "Add Account' then we want to copy columns L,M, and N from 'DCT Accounts' to the bottom of 'DCT'  Column M in 'DCT Accounts' will lookup to column B in 'DCT'.  And then if Column K says 'Close Account' then we want to delete the entire row if it exists in 'DCT'  (same concept of Column M in 'DCT Accounts' is the lookup to column B in 'DCT' sheet.

Comment: @Amateurhour35:  If you did not say things without being covered by the workbook reality, I insist to make the code running in the way the workbook is. So, **will the code be able to find a matchup between the values in column D:D of the first sheet and column B:B of the second one**? Please, simple answer by Yes or No. I come again with the same question: "Since only columns A, B and C ar copied in the other worksheet, theoretically the key should be in the same column...  How to match something from the first worksheet with something not being copied previously?

Comment: Column D in 'DCT Accounts' will lookup to Column B in 'DCT'.  So the answer is yes.  Upon running it, no data is produced, it just errors out.  No need for 3 additional columns.

Comment: @Amateurhour35: OK. The code is tested on my computer. Now, let us debug it. I asked above if the sheet "DCT" contains any data. So, does it contain data? Or, better, if not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? If yes, you can use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is easy to be used and free...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223045/discussion-between-amateurhour35-and-faneduru).

Comment: The quick answer is , 'DCT' contains several columns of data, and is basically a running list that the VBA you coded up above would help maintain on a weekly basis (adding or removing rows based on the columns we reference up above).  So in other words, DCT has about 700 rows worth of data, and every week we either Add accounts or remove them depending upon the filtering I set in the 'DCT Accounts' sheet.  One very dumb question, but in 'DCT Accounts' column D is a formula, not sure if that matters.  Going to add a screenshot in a sec

Comment: Just added a screenshot to original post of what DCT Sheet looks like,   'DCT Accounts' is similar structure where headers for the columns start on row 3 , and actual data is row 4.

Comment: Edited original post to also include the DCT Accounts format (i kept it 1 row for now just because it's confidential data, let me know if you need any other info to help

Comment: @Amateurhour35: Even if the code works now as needed, what about my idea about **replacing "Add Account" from the sheet with "Account added", after inputting the range in the array and doing something similar in case of "Close Account"/"Account closed"**? This will be good for traceability point of view and also to avoid adding twice the same accounts, pressing the button by mistake before manually changing the status... Or preliminary checking if the key already exists, but this will waste Excel resources and takes time, for a bigger range. I asked you on chat, but you probably went to bed...

Comment: @Amateurhour35: I will like to remind that we here, when somebody answer your question in ia satisfactory way, vote the answer up and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works.